# Multivariable Calculus and Differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, piecewise-continuity

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{y^3}{x^2+y^2} &(x,y) \neq \ \mathbb{(0,0)}\\ 0 &  (x,y)=(0,0) \\ \end{cases}$$

Evaluate $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ and $D_\overrightarrow{u}f(0,0)$

I tried directly taking the derivative to no avail (obviously) so then I tried to use the definition of partial derivative which also left me without a correct solution. Also I have proved that it is continuous (Sertoz Theorem) but how would I prove that it is also differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: calculate $\Big|\frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||}\Big|$ since $f(0,0)=0$. $||\cdot||_2$ seems convenient here.

Comment: @zwim : If the difference between $||\cdot||$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is not conspicuous enough to you, look at $||a|| ||b||$ versus $\|a\|\|b\|.$ That's why the latter is standard usage.

Comment: @zwim either you wrote the TeX commands in a hurry or I don't know what $||\cdot||_2$ means

Comment: @MichaelHardy Could you explain what zwim meant to say?

Comment: $\lVert(x,y)\lVert_2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ this is just the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(t,0) - f(0,0)}{t} = 0, \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0,t) - f(0,0)}{t} = 1\ \ $$

Next, I will show that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Let $\vec{u}$ be a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\vec{u} = u_1e_1 + u_2e_2$, where $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ are the canonical basis vectors. Then,
$$
D_{\vec{u}}f(0,0) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f((0,0) + t(u_1, u_2))-f(0,0)}{t}\\
= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(tu_1, tu_2)}{t} \\
= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t^3u_2^3}{t(t^2u_1^2 + t^2u_2^2)} = u_2^3 
$$
If $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$, then
$$D_{\vec{u}}f(0,0) = \nabla f(0,0) \cdot \vec{u} \\
= f_x(0,0)u_1 + f_y(0,0)u_2 = u_2
$$
However, this contradicts what we have above, as $\vec{u}$ can be chosen so that $u_2\ne u_2^3$.

Comment: shouldn't it be limit as $t\rightarrow0$?

Comment: right, typo. Thanks, I've fixed it.

Comment: also should it be $u_3 \neq (u_3)^3$ or should it be $u_2 \neq (u_2)^3$

Comment: BTW thanks for the detailed explanation because I had just given up on it thinking that since the limit definition w.r.t $x$ was also $0$ that the question might be wrong!

Comment: I've fixed the typo, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using polar coordinates
$$\begin{gather}x = \rho\cos{\varphi}, \\ y=  \rho\sin{\varphi}.\end{gather}$$
we have
$${\frac{f(x,\,y) - f(0,\,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}} ={\frac{f(\rho\cos{\varphi},\,\rho\sin{\varphi}) - 0}{\rho}} = {\frac{\rho^3\sin^3{\varphi}}{\rho^2\rho}} = \sin^3 \varphi$$

Since this can take arbitrary values when $\varphi$ changes, it means that the limit do not exists and so $Df(0,\,0)$ do not exists, i.e $f$ not differentiable in $(0,0)$.

Comment: There is a $\rho^2$ missing on denominator coming from $f(x,y)$ denominator.

Comment: @zwim: Thanks for your edit.